# Need help resolving my sql file error 1064

Tags: sql

I am using a sql file that looks like this

```
ALTER TABLE `users` 
    ADD COLUMN `crypto` VARCHAR(255) NULL '{"bitcoin": 0, "ethereum": 0, "bitcoin-cash": 0, "bitcoin-sv": 0, "litecoin": 0, "binance-coin": 0, "monero": 0, "dash": 0, "zcash": 0, "maker": 0}';
```

and i am getting this error

> /* SQL-fel (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''{"bitcoin": 0, "ethereum": 0, "bitcoin-cash": 0, "bitcoin-sv": 0, "litecoin"...' at line 1 *

i dont know what could be the problem

Comment: Why are you storing data as a JSON blob instead of as columns? And **exactly what** RDBMS are you using?

Comment: If the `'{"bitcoin": 0, "ethere` part is meant to be a default-value for the column then you should use the `DEFAULT` specifier - and the column should probably be `NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL` or so.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already said, if you mean to add a column with a default value, the correct syntax is this:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` 
ADD COLUMN `crypto` VARCHAR(255) NULL default 
'{"bitcoin": 0, "ethereum": 0, "bitcoin-cash": 0, "bitcoin-sv": 0, "litecoin": 0, 
"binance-coin": 0, "monero": 0, "dash": 0, "zcash": 0, "maker": 0}';
```

It works even if you don't set the type as `NVARCHAR(1000)`.

Comment: If you can upvote or accept the answer is useful for others that meet the same problem. Thanks!